# How to source relative files

Tags: bash, zsh

I have scripts in sub folders, or I would like to have - but "No such file or directory" or "Can't open" etc.

I would like to be able to run top.sh script, and each "sub folder" scripts independently. Can you do that?

folder structure:

```
top
- level1
- - level2
```

top.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh

. ./level1/level.sh

echo "top"
```

level1.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh

. ./level2/level2.sh
# Works on Mac - not in Ubuntu
# . ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/level2/level2.sh 

echo "level1"
```

level2.sh

```
echo "level2"
```

Note: Tried using `BASH_SOURCE` but it does not work in Ubuntu

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`? They're not the same.

Comment: Relative pathnames are relative to the user's working directory, not the directory containing the script.

Comment: Why would you use `$BASH_SOURCE` in a `zsh` script?

Comment: What would you use in zsh? I only found BASH_SOURCE for bash. Was hoping for some general way of doing it.